# Keep an HTA window from resizing

Tags: hta

I have an HTA which I always want to have the same size. I've already kept the window from being maximized by using `<hta:application maximizebutton="no"` but I also want to keep it from being resised by dragging the mouse from the border of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this below:

```
<HTA:APPLICATION
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
    SCROLL="NO"
    BORDER="DIALOG"
/>
```

Note - If you want to allow user to scroll, change **`SCROLL`** string from **`NO`** to **`YES`**

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="sample"
    APPLICATIONNAME="sample"
    BORDER="dialog"
    MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
    SCROLLFLAT="yes"
    CAPTION="yes"
    SELECTION="no"
    INNERBORDER="no"
    ICON=""
    SCROLL="no"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal" />
```